# @font-face src: local - How to use the local font if the user already has it?

Tags: css, font-face

What is the right way to use `@font-face` so that the browser will not download the font if the user already have it?

I am using @font-face to define DejaVu, which is already installed on my system (linux).
Firefox is not downloading the font, but Chromium is downloading it every time!

My CSS code, based on [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-define-bold-italic-using-font-face) look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';
    src: url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.eot');
    src: local('DejaVu Serif'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('DejaVuSerif-webfont.svg#webfontCFu7RF0I') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* ... @font-face definitions for italic and bold omitted ... */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';
    src: url('DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
    src: local('DejaVu Serif Bold Italic'), url('DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.svg#webfontQAewh7pf') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698319/css-font-face-what-does-src-local-mean

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you want to check for local files first do:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Green Sans Web';
src:
    local('Green Web'),
    local('GreenWeb-Regular'),
    url('GreenWeb.ttf');
}
```

There is a more elaborate description [of what to do here](http://www.broken-links.com/2009/06/30/checking-for-installed-fonts-with-font-face-and-local/).

Comment: What if we have 2 `src`s (as in OP's example)? Do we put `local` on the first or second one?

Comment: How do you know what the correct font names are?

Comment: Yea I don't get how you know what the value is to pass into `local()` ?

Comment: Ah ok, @Awn, it's the "full name" and "Postscript name". On Mac OSX can be found following https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79875/how-can-i-get-the-postscript-name-of-a-ttf-font-installed-in-os-x

Comment: Thanks, this helped me resolve a problem with Firefox downloading an external font instead of using the locally installed one (it seems to require the Postscript name as of now).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still need it:

Download the font you need from fonts.google.com, then set your CSS file:

```css
@font-face { font-family: roboto-regular; src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'); }
body {
  font-family: roboto-regular;
}
```

Note: make sure the path to the TTF file is correct.

Comment: This will only work if your fonts folder is located in your css folder. In the case you store your fonts outside the css folder you have to use src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf');

Answer (score 0):

Rather an old discussion, but is someone comes to this place, here some more infos.

1. goto https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts
2. select there the font(s) you need/want
3. downlaod the selected fonts
4. copy the displayed css

The copied css code may not be 100% correct, so below what I have been using (and works perfectly):

```css
/* open-sans-regular - vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic     */
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-display: swap;
src: url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: local('');
src: url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg'), /* Legacy iOS */
url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
url('fonts/open-sans-v34-vietnamese_latin_hebrew_greek_cyrillic-regular.woff2') format('woff2'); /* Super Modern Browsers */
}
```

Inside the edited code you can delete the comments (after each url(..) line.
And finally - as tipp: pack the source, in general the packed file is ~ 30% smaller (and your website will have the benefit).

Edit: updated code snippet to be actual.
The font ordering is based on the fact, that browsers read from bottom to top (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835957/3450837).

It includes also the "bulletproof" solution where a smiley (which one you want to use is up to you) is used (to prevent wasting bandwidth) - see https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/