# CSS Font Face, only download when font is non existent

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've included a custom font on my website (`Segoe UI`), however the font file are around 1mb, which takes a few seconds to load the first time.

I'm on a Mac, and the font is not shipped with OSX. However, as far as my knowledge goes, it's included with Windows.

How can I make CSS **only** load the font if it's not already existing on the client?

Comment: do you accept a javascript solution?

Comment: I would prefer if I could keep it in the CSS. However, if that is not possible, `JS` will have to do. It's a pain having such a slow loading frontpage

Comment: See if this possible duplicate: [@font-face src: local - How to use the local font if the user already have it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-have-it) may help you.

Comment: Segoe UI is not a free font, and you would need a permission from Microsoft to use it as a web font.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `local('Segoe UI')` worked out. Seems like it prioritizes the sources from first to last.

Here's the working code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Segoe;
    src: local('Segoe UI'), url('fonts/segoeui.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/segoeui.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Be wary that you'll need permission by Microsoft to use this font on your website.

Comment: Do you confirm that you actually don't need the first "src" line in your code?