# how to type this cloud in font-face in local

Tags: css, font-face, symbols

Hi all I'm trying to use the interstate font face (see image below).

Now there is this one property called local, I have no idea what that is but I'm sure some searching will answer that.

My problem is I am not able to type this cloud (please see image) can you please help me. the font seems to be working with a question mark in its place.

[image: cloud is pointed to with red arrow]

Comment: Maybe this code could help you with the local attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-has-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ☁

This is one of Unicode's [Miscellaneous Symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf):

```
Weather and astrological symbols
    ...
    2601 ☁ CLOUD
          = cloudy weather
```

From this you can use `&#x2601;` to display it on a page.

Comment: much thanks! especially for the fast reply!! espeically for that pdf and double especially for giving the straight up answer, so i can get this thing im working on done right away and do some research with that pdf later.