# Exo font face local

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

On **FontSquirrell**, I have converted the font **Exo** from **ttf** to all the possible versions, I have put all the fonts in **fonts>exo** and in the **CSS** file this code:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'exoblack';
    src: url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.svg#exoblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Why can't I see the font in local?  I tried to put **src: local**:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'exoblack';
    src: url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.eot');
    **src: local('exoblack'), url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype');**
    src: url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/exo/exo-black-webfont.svg#exoblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try going here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-has-it

Comment: As I know some browsers like a IE11, have troubles to display custom fonts in local. Try to run it on server.