# will all font types in @font-face be downloaded?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-face

Wondering if I include various font formats within @font-face in CSS, all of them will be downloaded no matter whether they will be used in the browser, or only the one that is used in the browser will be download?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-web-font';
    src: url('webfont.eot');
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: If your font lies in your system/local then it will not be downloaded everytime , but if not then it will be downloaded everytime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face src: local - How to use the local font if the user already has it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-has-it)

Comment: Only one will be downloaded depending on the browser or none at all if it's already cache in the browser.