# tailwind use font from local files globally

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Currently I'm doing this in my style tags

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

but I downloaded the Roboto font and would like to know how I can configure Tailwind to use those files and the font globally for all elements.

**Sidenote:**

I'm using Vuejs and followed the guide on how to setup Tailwind for Vue from here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJcvpuELcZo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@font-face src: local - How to use the local font if the user already has it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-has-it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this didn't help :/ I don't know if things are different when using VueJs..

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can customize Tailwind if it was installed as a dependency to your project using `npm install tailwindcss`

Steps:

- copy the downloaded font and place it inside a `fonts` folder inside your project.
- run `npx tailwind init`, to generate an empty `tailwind.config.js`
- Inside `tailwind.config.js` add `fontFamily` inside `extend` and specify the font family to override (Tailwind's default family is `sans`). Place the newly added font family at the beginning ([order matters](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family/#customizing))

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'sans': ['Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif']
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

**Important**: Using `extend` will add the newly specified font families without overriding Tailwind's entire font stack.

Then in the main `tailwind.css` file (where you import all of tailwind features), you can import your local font family. Like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: local('Roboto'), url(./fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format('ttf');
}

@tailwind utilities;
```

Now recompile the CSS. If you're following [Tailwind's documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#4-process-your-css-with-tailwind), this is  typically done using [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss):

```
postcss css/tailwind.css -o public/tailwind.css
```

If you're not using postcss, you can run:

```
npx tailwindcss build css/tailwind.css -o public/tailwind.css
```

Your newly added font family should now be rendered.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. I think your solution seems to be the cleanest one. I'm using VueJs and installed tailwind via npm as described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJcvpuELcZo for the last part you described I think I have to navigate to the css directory and use this command then `npx tailwindcss build main.css -o main.css` but this generates a huge css file and seems to be a production only file ...

Comment: The CSS generated will be pretty huge because it includes all of Tailwind's utility classes. If you're looking to generate a leaner build check out the screencast "[optimizing for production](https://tailwindcss.com/course/optimizing-for-production)"

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure if I should call `npx tailwindcss build main.css -o main.css` in the src directory when developing with a frontend framework like Vue, Angular or React. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, you would want to use the scripts that come with the specific framework to build a optimized version of your project.

Comment: king of the north

Comment: as of Tailwind 2.1.0 use the `@layer` directive to include your fonts. See my answer below.

Comment: For what it's worth, for me, I needed to change the format from 'ttf' to 'truetype' to make it work using this answer.

Answer (score 87):

@Juan Marcos' answer is correct but slightly deprecated. As of v2.1.0, Tailwind recommends [in their docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles#font-face-rules) to use the `@layer` directive for loading local fonts:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: Proxima Nova;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(/fonts/proxima-nova/400-regular.woff) format("woff");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: Proxima Nova;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url(/fonts/proxima-nova/500-medium.woff) format("woff");
  }
}
```

> By using the @layer directive, Tailwind will automatically move those styles to the same place as @tailwind base to avoid unintended specificity issues.

> Using the @layer directive will also instruct Tailwind to consider those styles for purging when purging the base layer. Read our documentation on optimizing for production for more details.

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer

See also: [Customizing the default font](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing-the-default-font)

Comment: stackoverflow should show latest answers on top . thanks for this

Comment: for ttf font, no need to give format

Comment: it is still unclear to me how I then use the font

Comment: Use `font-style: italic` for italic

Answer (score 8):

My way, full plugin style, one local font, one https font, no need for @import, no need for `<link>`:

```
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'sans': ['Red Hat Display', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        'damion': ['Damion'],
      }
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addBase }) {
      addBase({
        '@font-face': {
            fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
            fontWeight: '300',
            src: 'url(/src/common/assets/fonts/RedHatDisplay-VariableFont_wght.ttf)'
        }
      })
    }),
    plugin(function ({ addBase }) {
      addBase({
        '@font-face': {
            fontFamily: 'Damion',
            fontWeight: '400',
            src: 'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/damion/v10/hv-XlzJ3KEUe_YZkamw2.woff2) format(\'woff2\')'
        }
      })
    }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1 - extract the downloaded font into a file ex `./fonts`

2 - create a stylesheet in the same folder and add this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'x-font-name';
    src: local('x-font-name'), local('x-font-name'),
        url('x-font-name.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('x-font-name.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

3 - import the stylesheet into input.css where you already have base, components, and utilities ex:

```
@import url('./assets/fonts/stylesheet.css');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4 - Go to the tailwind config file and add your font to theme extend ex :

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    fontFamily: {
      'FontName': ['x-font-name','Roboto'],
      'FontName-2': ['x-name-2','Roboto']
    },
  },
},
```

5 - use it in the HTML ex : `class="font-FontName"`

Comment: IDKW, but I have to provide the full path to the src as `src: url("assets/fonts/fontName.ttf"`. Any idea?

Comment: Incase someone is interested: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-tailwind-css

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:​** Download the font and save it locally
You go to the ​Download Family ​button at the top right and you will get a zip or folder with
different font weights.
From what we downloaded, we move the file ​static/​Oswald-Bold.ttf​ ​to a ​new folder
/dist/fonts/Oswald
,​ which we create.

**Step 2​:** Import the font locally
In the ​tailwind.css ​within ​@layer base​ and above the headings we add:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Oswald;
src: url(/dist/fonts/Oswald/Oswald-Bold.ttf) format("​truetype​") or ttf;
```

If we now run ​npm run watch​, the font-family is immediately compiled into styles.css, and if
we search for “Oswald” we get:
Tip: ​If something doesn't work, you can click on the link in the URL while holding down the
“CTRL” key to see if the path is correct!

**Step 3:**​ Extend the Tailwindcss theme
In the ​tailwind.config.js ​we add under “​theme​” and “​extend​”:

```
theme: {
extend: {
fontFamily: {
headline: ['Oswald']
}
},
```

The name “headline” ​can be chosen freely​ here!

Answer (score 2):

i just add this `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;500&display=swap');` inside index.css and update tailwind.config.js with the following :

```
theme: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'],
        serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif'],
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

We can add a custom font-family in tailwind in 2 steps:

1. Add custom font

We can import font from `fonts.googleapis.com` and add it to `index.html` head or we can use `@import`, `@font-face`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

2. Extend tailwind font-family

Next, I will extend tailwind font-family `sans` in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Raleway', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is for JavaScript, but if anyone is using this for Flask and Tailwind CSS (as I was) here is what I had to do. I put the font face in a separate CSS file in my static folder. In my HTML templates, I just linked the style sheet after linking my Tailwind CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='gameStyles.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles2.css') }}"/>
```

And just for reference, here is what I put in my styles2.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'reg';
    src: url(../static/ObjectSans-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'bol';
    src: url(../static/ObjectSans-Heavy.otf);
}

body {
    font-family: 'reg';
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'bol';
}
```

It would be nice if there was a better way to do this, but this was the only way I could get it to work. Hopefully this helps!