# CSS: Bulletproof @font-face: Smiley variation

Tags: css, embedded-fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS @font-face - what does “src: local('☺')” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698319/css-font-face-what-does-src-local-mean)

Hi,

I came across this article - Bulletproof @font-face syntax

http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Here is the syntax of bulletproof,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
         url('GraublauWeb.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

but I don't understand what he says about the smiley face in the local(). What does it mean? Is it a standdard which is supported across browsers, PCs and Apples? Can I put something else in?

Here is what he explains,

> Added 2010.02.04: There has been
>   concern over specifying local font
>   names. The primary reason is that you
>   cede control to the user's machine,
>   potentially showing a locally
>   installed font instead of the one you
>   want to serve. While that will load
>   faster, there's a very small chance
>   the file could be wrong.
>
> To account for this gotcha, I've
>   specified a local font name of '☺'.
>   Yes, it's a smiley face. The OpenType
>   spec indicates any two-byte unicode
>   characters won't work in a font name
>   on Mac at all, so that lessens the
>   likelihood that someone actually
>   released a font with such a name. This
>   technique is recommended if you think
>   a locally installed version of this
>   font is not in your best interest.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smiley is used as the name of a font that cannot possibly exist (or is, at least, extremely unlikely) so that a local font that happens to have the same name as the desired fony will not be used

Comment: But do you actually need a `local()` statement?  Is it redundant?  Shouldn't the browser use your first `url()` without it?