# Do I need to use src:local("?") to use webfonts in css

Tags: css, local, webfonts

I had used a code for web-font, from a tutorial.Not sure what the src:local(), means.Is it necessary to include local()?or is it just fine to use font-family:... and src:url()?

```
@font-face
{
font-family:"F25";
src:url("f25_executive-webfont.eot");
src:local("F25"),
    url("f25_executive-webfont.ttf")format("truetype");
}

#quote
{
font-family:"F25",Georgia;
text-align:center;
}
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need it. It's for when the users already have the same font on their own computer. Here's a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698319/css-font-face-what-does-src-local-mean

Comment: @ralph m, Thanks for reply.I have gone through that post and not fully understood things about smiley-face.But anyway things are bit clear now.

Comment: The smiley face prevents the user's computer from using a local font with the same name. In your case, that's highly unlikely anyway, as most people won't have that font installed.