# How to change the font family of jquery datatables export buttons

Tags: css, datatables, webfonts

I have used the datatables export buttons (https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) on my web site.
However in my web site I'm using custom font-family. In my main css the code is the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFontCapital;
    src: url('../font/MyFontCapital.otf'); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFontSansRegular;
    src: url('../font/MyFontSans-Regular.otf'); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFontSansMedium;
    src: url('../font/ MyFontSans-Medium.otf'); 
}
```

And the css files I use are the following:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/plugins/dataTables/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

While the additional js files are the following:

```
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/dataTables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to change the fonts that the export button use (CSV , Excel, PDF, Print)

I tried to add the on my main css the code:

```
.dt-button {
  font-family: MyFontCapital;
  src: url('../font/MyFontCapital.otf');
}
```

or

```
.dt-button-collection{
  font-family: MyFontCapital;
  src: url('../font/MyFontCapital.otf');
}
```

But didn't work. I also searched the datatables site but didn't find any example that font-family is set during datatable initialization.
Any idea what I should do?

Comment: It looks like your fonts cannot be found locally. Sure `@font-face` can find them? Remove `src` from `dt-button..` classes, won't work anyway as it is a `@font-face` specific property.

Comment: @RenevanderLende font-face can find them. I removed the the src but the buttons could not see the specific fonts.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with @font-face but there is a difference between local and remote url(), so you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698319/css-font-face-what-does-src-local-mean.

Comment: This font is applied to another elements in your web page?

Comment: @MajidBasirati Yes these fonts are applied in several elements in my web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your style definitions more important e.g.

```
.dt-button {
  font-family: MyFontCapital !important;
}
```

The `src` in .dt-button styling is not needed.

Also, you have an extra space in path to font:

```
    font-family: MyFontSansMedium;
    src: url('../font/ MyFontSans-Medium.otf');
```